# Commodore 64 Development Tools for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, c64

Which tools do you use for cross-development for C64 on OSX?

Which assembler, text editor or IDE, gfx, sprite, charset editors?

Or do you simply prefer Windows environment via parallels desktop or bootcamp?

Comment: I have found a very useful command line tool called dust. It installs OSX binary of ACME, VICE64, Sublime Text 2 and some other tools. (can can be downloaded from http://www.dustlayer.com)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**For MacOS X**

Text Editor: Eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/)

Assembler: WUDSN (http://www.wudsn.com/)

Graphics Editor: GraFX2 (http://code.google.com/p/grafx2/)

Sprite/Charset Editors: You will probably need to develop your own tools or use Windows running on a virtual machine.

**For Windows**

Text Editor: Eclipse (http://www.eclipse.org/), EditPlus (http://www.editplus.com/) or UltraEdit (http://www.ultraedit.com/)

Assembler: KickAssembler (http://www.theweb.dk/KickAssembler/Main.php) or ACME Cross Assembler (http://www.esw-heim.tu-clausthal.de/~marco/smorbrod/acme/)

Graphics Editor: Timanthes (http://csdb.dk/release/?id=75871) or Project One (http://csdb.dk/release/?id=86776)

Sprite Editor: SpritePad (http://csdb.dk/release/?id=100657)

Charset Editor: CharPad (http://csdb.dk/release/?id=101863)

Answer (score 5):

Edit:
Relaunch64 is now available as stable build for Windows, OS X and Linux: http://www.popelganda.de/relaunch64.html

If you're interested in using ACME or 64tass on OS X as well, you find latest binaries there, too.

Relaunch64 is an C64-Assembler-IDE that specifically focuses on doing this job, without the need for comprehensive setting up before you can start.

In the course of the next days, version 3.1 will be released with much faster performance (see https://sourceforge.net/projects/relaunch64/files/3.1.0/).

Comment: Thanks, just voted up for Relaunch64, makes the life easier! I found a good link with explanation how to initially configure it: https://www.c64-wiki.com/wiki/Relaunch64

Answer (score 4):

I use Emacs 24.3 as my editor. Its stock `asm-mode` is ok for C64 code, even though it wasn't necessarily intended for that, but I think there are some dedicated C64 modes out there as well. My assembler of choice so far has been [TMPx](http://style64.org/release/tmpx-v1.0-style) ("Turbo Macro Pro cross") by Style. Works like a charm, and very fast for me when testing with VICE.

Edit: I've since switched to 64tass, which is a fair bit more helpful when it comes to macros, code organisation, debugging, etc. I did have to compile it myself for my Intel mac, but it was a snap.

Answer (score 2):

My main tools are [Sublime text 3](http://www.sublimetext.com/3), [Kick Assembler](http://www.theweb.dk/KickAssembler/) and the [Vice C64 emulator](http://www.viceteam.org/). I maintain and use the [Kick Assembler (C64) sublime package](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Kick%20Assembler%20%28C64%29), which in short has the following features:

- Syntax coloring
- Build, build and run, build and debug etc.
- Some snippets
- Code navigation / symbol list

More info about features and installation of the *Kick Assembler (C64) sublime package* [here](http://goatpower.org/).

I mostly use OSX, but sometimes also Windows, and since all three tools (including the Sublime package) work on both OSX and Windows i can be flexible.

I also use [TMPView](http://style64.org/release/tmpview-v1.3-style) to convert my old TASM-source-files. On the Windows side i use [DirMaster](http://style64.org/dirmaster) to handle old c64 disk images.

Comment: I'm on Sublime Text 2 and ACME. But I'm not happy with the syntax highlighter I am using. It doesn't support labels and !zone psedo opcode.

Does your syntax colouring work on Sublime Text 2? If so I'll give it a try.

Comment: @wizofwor: I think it works fine on Sublime Text 2, i just limited compatibility to version 3 in _Package Control_ to avoid the extra testing. A guy named Fix is developing an ACME-version from the _Kick Assembler (C64)_ package, available [here](http://csdb.dk/release/?id=126930). More info in forum [here](http://csdb.dk/forums/?roomid=11&topicid=99923).